# comment_question goes to comment_questions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have three models: posts, comments and questions. I have a link from my posts show page that's supposed to go to the questions show view. Instead it goes to the questions index view.

Here are the rake routes:

```
comment_question GET    /comments/:comment_id/questions/:id(.:format)        questions#show
comment_questions GET    /comments/:comment_id/questions(.:format)            questions#index
```

and here is the posts view:

```
<%= div_for(comment) do %>
<% comment.questions.select(:title).order('created_at desc').limit(3).each do |question| %> 
<%= link_to (question.title), comment_question_path(comment, @question) %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: If any of the below answers presented a solution to your question, please accept their answer by clicking on the check mark beside their answer. This will help future users searching for an answer to the same question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the helpers give you trouble you can always override them with manual implementation

```
<a href="<%= url_for :controller => 'comments', :action => 'show', :comment_id => comment.id, :id => question.id %>"><%= @question.title %></a>
```

Comment: No, you can use a variable... sorry about that just use `:id => question.id`. This can even be used in a for loop or anywhere you need a url. I actually prefer this method to the `link_to` helper. But that's just personal preference

Comment: Ok I might need some more assistance. :comment_id => :comment_id, :id => question.id gives me an :id thats nil.

Comment: oh, oops. Try `@question.id`. Basically whatever your question variable is, call `.id` on it.

Comment: Hmm weird. I'm getting an error 'Couldn't find Comment with id=@question' and the URL looks like localhost:3000/comments/@question.id?comment_id=comment_id

Comment: OK, so I re-looked over your code, you do need to use `question` and not `@question` as you are in a block and the variable you defined (`|question|`) is a representation of each object in `comment.questions...` So do switch that back to `question` and not `@question`. As to why you are getting `nil` that is odd, and might actually be the source of the problem, and why the helper wasn't working for you.

Comment: Sure, no problem. If you would like, I can help you further in a chat. Just let me know.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40081/discussion-between-user2759575-and-snarechops)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `question` instead of `@question` in your `each` block:

```
<%= link_to question.title, comment_question_path(comment, question) %>
```

Comment: Nope, this goes to the same place.

Comment: @user2759575 Does your log show any redirects when you click on the link, or does it go directly to the index view?

Comment: It looks like it goes directly to the index.